# When i type ?leaderboard this error pops up in the console but the command gets executed perfectly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here's the code:

https://hastebin.com/icagenixid.typescript

Here is the error

https://hastebin.com/kijivefahi.typescript

Comment: you have an unhandled promise rejection in line 14 of leaderboard.js ... you need to handle the rejection by some means - if only we could see the code

Comment: Hello sorry about that i edited the post and added hastebin links for both the error and the code :)

Comment: nah, code and error in the question - it's like 30 lines all up

Comment: Oh, I see why it's an unhandled promise rejection ... you've made `run` into an `async` function for absolutely no reason ... remove `async` from `run` ... since you NEVER use `await` in that function it makes no sense - your actual error is that `client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[2])` is undefined - what is `money[i].ID.split('_')[2]`? nevermind ... use `[1]` instead ... since arrays are 0-based ... and you want the second value which is index 1

Comment: oki thanks for the explanation im kind of new to these kind of stuff n all so yeahh thanks again